# Solving a System of Equations for ( a , b , c )

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics, symmetric-polynomials

Given:
$$a + b - c = 2$$ 
$$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - ab + ac + bc = 1009$$

Solve for a positive integer triplet $(a, b, c)$.

I'm not exactly sure how to approach this problem. The second equation doesn't seem factorable. I've tried plugging in different values of $a, b, c$ found in the first equation into the second equation, but that hasn't been very helpful. Any suggestions would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: @MathLover but how did you get that?

Comment: How about using the first equation to eliminate $c$ from the second equation? Then you'll get a conic where you need to find the integer points.

Comment: I tried doing that, but it just made the second equation complicated and I didn't know how to proceed from there

Answer (score 3):

Substitute $c=a+b-2$ in the second equation, and you get
$$ a^2 + a b + b^2 - 2 a - 2 b = 335 $$
and thus
$$ \frac{3}{4} (a+b)^2 + \frac{1}{4} (a-b)^2 - 2 (a+b) = 335 $$
or
$$  (3a + 3b - 4)^2 + 3 (a-b)^2 = 4036 $$
There are finitely many integer solutions to $x^2 + 3 y^2 = 4036$...